# Blank screen appearing in kivy whenever running

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I don't know what is happening in the code, to me it looks all fine but whenever running the code it is showing a black screen. When I change the return type to 'Builder.load_file' it is giving an err0r of:

```
[CRITICAL] [Application ] No window is created. Terminating application run.
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event5
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event5>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[ERROR  ] [Base        ] No event listeners have been created
[ERROR  ] [Base        ] Application will leave
```

Here is the code for main.py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MyGLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('timer0.kv')

if __name__=='__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

here is the code for .kv file:

```
#:kivy 2.1.0

<MyGLayout>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    size:root.width,root.height
    spacing:20
    padding:20
    Label:
        text:'Hello name!!'
```

If anyone knows what is wrong with the code, please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .kv file, you should remove the <>.

Use:

```
MyGLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    size:root.width,root.height
    spacing:20
    padding:20
    Label:
        text:'Hello name!!'
```